# How can I detect changes in DIV element using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Hi I need trigger a custom function every time a DIV changes its size, this must be done with pure JavaScript and has to be compatible with IE 10-11, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. the problem is that I don´t know how to listen this resize event in a DIV element, can someone tell me a way to achieve this?

Comment: IE10 has a short lifespan are you aware of this

Comment: "DIV changes its size" How/why excatly that happens? Due to a content change? Due to `window` resize? Something else? Divs just don't automagically change their size.